# Running a cron job through cPanel to start a Python file

Tags: python, cron, cpanel

Trying to get the server to automatically run a Python script that rewrites some code for a Podcast site I'm developing. Since I'm new to web dev and Python, I wrote some test code that writes a test file.

My file is located at:

```
/path/to/script/script.py
```

and here's my Python code

```
open('test.txt', 'w').close()
```

Should my file begin with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Or

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Does it matter? Why wouldn't this code work?

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to your title, or provide an answer in your question. Instead, add an answer below and then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution - The opening didn't matter. It was saving to a different folder on the server. Not sure why it sends there. Maybe that's the way the hosting works. Here's the solution. I'll deploy the full code now.

```
open('full/file/path/test.txt', 'w').close()
```